# react-native-fbsdk-next Custom data in Params not appearing in Events Manager

Tags: typescript, react-native, react-native-fbsdk-next

I have an issue sending custom parameters to the Facebook Events Manager using the library `react-native-fbsdk-next`.

I can see the events coming in, but they don't have any parameters.

Here is the example of how I send the data:

```
 const payload: Params = {
        screen_class: 'home',
        screen_name: 'home',
      }

      // Facebook analytics
      AppEventsLogger.logEvent('test_event1', payload)
```

Comment: got solution ???

Comment: @priyanka The issue was because of the setup of the package. This implementation worked well when I made the correct configuration

Comment: Can you please share some code snippet as I am also able to see events triggering but not able to see parameters sent along with that

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not have access to it anymore. Good luck! @priyanka